# Webpack - Import function from existing js(minified) files without exports

Tags: javascript, webpack

Our existing project includes js files(minified). Now, I am trying to use webpack for newer modules. How should I import the existing js functions?

file1.js (concatenated files using gulp-concat) 
(original file - ajax.js)

```
function sendAjax(param1, param2, url) {
...
}

function checkValues(form) {
...
}
```

Now, if I want to import the above function what should I do?

```
import * as ajaxUtils from 'path_to_file1';
```

or

```
import * as ajaxUtils from 'path_to_ajax'; and then - 

ajaxUtils.sendAjax(param1, param2, url)
```

Since, the old js file has many functions, how should I export those functions? Or should I even export, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you've shown from `file1.js` are globals, so you shouldn't need to import them. If you're using a linter that warns you of undeclared identifiers, you may need to tell it that those functions exist in the modules in which you use them. That often involves a comment in a predefined format at the top of the file — which will be useful for humans maintaining the code, too.